# bulk importing magento

Tags: magento, bulk-import

I need help with importing bulk products to a store in our magento multi-store configuration. the products should have the names, images, categories, descriptions, custom options (sizing with fixed pricing). I created a csv and was able to successfully upload products but the sizing did not show along with the pricing. Also the images did not appear on front end. I uploaded into media/import and edited in the three csv columns. I also created a direct under the letter system for example if the image name started with ab I would created directory a/b/image.jpg and put them in the three areas of the csv. any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest to look over Magmi: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: http://www.learnmagento.org/magento-tutorials/import-products-with-custom-options-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

Try: [Magmi Mass Importer](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page)
Better than spending the $$ on Unirgy RapidFlow if you don't have any budget.

Answer (score 0):

Please download Magmi Plugin. http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/
And put Magmi under the root direcotry of your site
and run www.Yourdomain.com/magmi/web/magmi.php
Now configure the magmi according to your requirment.
(Note: you need to put csv file under the var/import)
It you want to Upload images You need also magmi image plugin
Download link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/files/magmi-0.7/plugins/packages/(magmi_extra_plugins_20120328.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding one of the products to be imported manually. Then export it from the admin panel and see what corrections should be made to the csv.